# .off not unbinding animationend event

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Alright, so I am making an animated menu that slides/expands tabs back and forth and will look fluid.  I have it all working except for unbinding the animationend event which I am attaching to the clicked tab.  So pretty much you click a tab, a listener is attached to it for the end of the animations and on the click of the next tab I want to unbind the listener to the tab that was previously clicked.  However, I cannot get the .off function to fire for some reason.  Here is my code below

```
var $featuredTab = this.$('.featured'),
    $tabContainer = $(e.target).parent(),
    $menu = this.$el,
    index = $tabContainer.index(),
    count = $tabContainer.parent().children().length; 

    if($featuredTab.length > 0) {
        $menu.off('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', $featuredTab, function() {
            console.log('off');
            //do stuff
        });
    }

    $tabContainer.addClass('featured');


    $menu.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', $tabContainer, function(e) {
            console.log(e.originalEvent);
            //do stuff
    });
```

any ideas as to why the off event isn't firing?

Comment: It's about unbinding jQuery events.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are treating second parameter as a selector then you are using `on` incorrectly. The second parameter is a selector(string) where you are passing an object. The second(selector) and  third(data) parameters are optional.

Take a look here - http://api.jquery.com/on/

However you can try this.

```
$menu.off('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd');
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli The selector is optional. When you pass in a data object, it'll be available in `event.data` for the triggered event handler.

Comment: it is... just didn't feel like putting all the code in.  got it figured out, just ended up attaching to selected element

Answer (score 0):

Because `off()` doesn't trigger an event.

> The `off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

It looks like you want to unbind any events that were previously attached to the menu:

```
// this removes ALL events
$menu.off('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd');
```

If you want to only remove your event, see [this example](http://api.jquery.com/off/#example-3) from the documentation.